# man command not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, manpage

My `man` command is not working at all on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Unlike most of the cases I have found described in the internet, where there is an error message after calling `man`, I do not get any output/ error message at all

If I type `which man`

I will get `/usr/bin/man`. And I have checked with `echo PATH` that`/usr/bin` is on my `PATH`.

I have already tried `sudo apt install --reinstall man-db`, restarted the terminal, but no success.

Does anyone know what the problem can be?

Comment: What do you get if you try `whereis man` ?  This should provide any locations for `man`, plus the locations for the manual pages (for the command `man`)

Comment: I get `man: /usr/bin/man /usr/local/man /usr/share/man /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz` None of them work by calling `man` with the full path (some are directories). But the `which` command will tell me which `man` linux will call when calling `man`, right? As I described in my question it is /usr/bin/man, which is in my $PATH

Comment: maybe you can run `strace man` and then paste the debug info in some nopaste site?(since the info would be long)

Comment: I would check you have some free disk space (`df -h`) in case it needs it to operate.  Next I would `dpkg -S /usr/bin/man` to ensure your found program comes from `man-db` (as expected).   I'm not sure what you mean by "*calling man with the full path*" as to access page 1 you `man 1 man`, to access page 7 `man 7 man` (which doesn't use the path; unless you meant `/usr/bin/man 1 man` to view page 1).   If you check file type of  your binary (ie. `file /usr/bin/man`) do you get a ELF LSB shared object dyn.linked of correct architecture?

Comment: To answer your comments: 1. space should not be a problem, 2. calling man with the full path I mean typing `/usr/bin/man` instead of just `man`. But, again, this does not work either. 3. the output of `file /usr/bin/man` is `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=c80771d215f4d9df4bf138ec9cfbf23bc58c950d, stripped`

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I am experiencing the same with an 18.04 lxc container.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it by running the following command:

```
sudo man <command>
```

Comment: It works, but why does it only work with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

If `man --version` gives the correct version info, but you are still not seeing output for `man ls`, `man` may not be using the right "pager" (the program that displays pages of information).  You can explicitly designate `less` as the pager (see the `-P` option in [the documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/man1.html):

```bsh
man -P less ls
```

When `-P` isn't used, then `man` uses the pager designated by `$MANPAGER` or `$PAGER`.  In my case, other programs, like `git diff` weren't working either, but adding the following to my `~/.bash_profile` allowed me to simply run `man ls` with the expected results:

```bsh
export PAGER=less
```

Notes: [@Gonzalo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1139214/1134729) displayed output for me as well but required running with `sudo`.  [A question](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1267858#p1267858) on a related discussion, led me to look into the pager issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had all the issues described here: [[SOLVED] 'Man' command does not work "No manual entry for ls"](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/%27man%27-command-does-not-work-no-manual-entry-for-ls-4175607007/).

My MANPATH environment variable was also wrong.

As instructed on that page, the quick is mainly about correcting MANPATH , for example, by entering the command below:

```
export MANPATH=/usr/share/man
```

That didn't work after reboot.

In my case, I had wrongly set `MANPATH` in my `.zshrc` file. Removing or correcting that was useful.